# CKAN errors in links and updates to resources after a change in domain name

Tags: caching, nginx, dns, ckan

A policy change forced me to have to change our domain name for ckan, someone had a bright idea to use the domain name for a different landing site and then redirect off to the ckan sever from there.

I have updated data records in the database to reflect the amended url in the resource tables. (resource, resource_revision , resource_view)

it was https://www.blah.....
the new url is http://hub.blah......

Some resources re now downloadable at the new domain, the pages show the correct domain name and links and buttons work correctly.

Some resources on the page show the old url and link to the old url where there is no document accessible. The document is present at the new url. I can see the records for the resource in the database reflect the new url in the database.

The previewers of the dataset are all showing the data as I would expect on those that have the correct url but not working on the pages where the url is incorrect on the screen.

New uploads are showing correctly on pages and correctly in the database.

I have restarted solr, nginx, apache and a reboot of the web server and the database server.

It looks like the pages that are out of date are cached but I cant find a way to refresh them and force the several hundred pages to re-query the database to get the correct information.

I see the same issue when the page is accessed externally and internally to my corporate network.

Anyone any more ideas?

Comment: Are those resources older than the ones that have the URLs working? Or is there something common between them?

Comment: Tip: "Write a title that summarizes the specific problem" http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What version of CKAN do you use?

Comment: Maybe the persisted_state.json of the filestore is corrupt, you could try to regenerate it using [ofs-hero](https://github.com/ckan/ofs-hero)

Comment: there are some that are correct and some bad, they are not date affected. when I edit the info about a resource it seems to then pick up the correct info so I am working through each dataset and making an edit. this is fixing all the resources for that dataset, its a pain but at least its solving my issue slowly. any edit on a resource also updates all other resources for the same dataset.

Comment: the version is 2.4 at the moment

Comment: not sure there is any corruption in that json as it can be changed by updating the comments and details about a resource, as I change one the others for that dataset change, but this does not affect other datasets until I change them too.

Comment: I quickly looked into this: I think the ckan.site_url is used to [generate the URL](https://github.com/ckan/ckan/blob/ckan-2.4.3/ckan/controllers/storage.py#L175) for an uploaded resource. So actually the old domain is saved in the database.

Comment: unfortunately some of the resources and datasets will not 'flip' to the new url when I edit the resource information but I get a timeout. this consistently happens to the ones like this, its not transitory. ones that don't flip never flip no matter how many times I try, I also cant add a new resource to these datasets. it does not depend on whether they resources are csv pdf or a mix or how many or few there are, I don't know what the common factor is for these ones but its about 10% of the datasets affected this way.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess would be that the URLs are wrong in the solr index, try to rebuild the whole solr index with this paster command (run in virtualenv):

```
paster --plugin=ckan search-index rebuild -c production.ini
```

Adapt to your config file accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

after a bit of a headache and a good nights sleep I added
the following to production.ini

ckan.datastore.sqlalchemy.pool_size=10
ckan.datastore.sqlalchemy.max_overflow=20

this worked for me